# how to obtain the signed transaction from metamask

Tags: metamask, wallets

I've develop an app which lets users sign transactions with Metamask.

I'd like to get the full signed transaction data (not only the transaction hash) from Metamask. Is there any way to do it?

Obtaining the signed transaction by transaction hash is not a viable solution for me because of the latency between a transaction being sent and included in a block.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use the [`eth_signTransaction`](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_signtransaction) JSON RPC method which will give you an RLP blob of the signed transaction. Afterwards you would need to decode this blob.

To broadcast the signed transaction, you would use [`eth_sendRawTransaction`](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_sendrawtransaction) with the blob from `eth_signTransaction`.

If you are using Ethers, the relevant methods would be [`signer.signTransaction`](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Signer-signTransaction) to sign the transaction, [`ethers.utils.parseTransaction`](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/transactions/#utils-parseTransaction) to parse the blob and [`provider.sendTransaction`](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-sendTransaction) to broadcast the signed transaction.

Comment: The catch is that Metamask doesn't support `eth_signTransaction` https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/3475#issuecomment-523680566.

Comment: yes, Metamask doesn't support eth_signTransaction, this is the root problem

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to read your user's signed transaction data before it is included in a block by miners.

One way to do this would be to run your own node and query the mempool to get list of pending transactions, filter for your user's public address and any other identifying data, and you'll get your user's raw transaction data, including the (r, s) signature data.

This will allow you to get your user's signed transaction after it's broadcasted but before it is included in a block.

Comment: yes, seams there is no api or function from metamask, directly